# How can i save fragment state which has cardview that are clicked and maintain their clicked state in the whole application life cycle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented the new architecture navigation component in my app, i have one activity that holds the five fragments , one of my five fragments has cardview that are set on click listeners after they are clicked the textview and color is changed to let my users know that they are already clicked, unfortunately when i navigate out of the fragments coming back after i have clicked them they are again reset to be unchecked lief they were before, how can i keep the persistance of them being checked in the whole activity also they are disabled once they are clicked, have tried several solutions but still cant get the right solutions.

** guys have managed to save the clicks on the cardview but the probmlem is it reall save but again when i navigate to another fragments it unchecks itself when i navigate away its again checks it self rather i want it to after being clicked it set to false so that i can prevent multiple clicks

**here is my  updated fragment with the cardviews**

```
        //saving button state after one click of the student
        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences (getContext ());
        mEditor = mPreferences.edit ();

        checkSharedPreferences ();

        //save the cardview preference

        if(cardView.isEnabled ())
        {
            //set a cardview state
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"true");
            //disabling the button after one click
            cardView.setEnabled (true);
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the color of the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#2b43f");
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the textcolor pf the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#ffffff");
            mEditor.commit ();
        } else
        {
            //set a cardview state
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"false");
            //disabling the button after one click
            cardView.setEnabled (false);
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the color of the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#ffffff");
            mEditor.commit ();

            //save the textcolor pf the cardview
            mEditor.putString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#2b434f");
            mEditor.commit ();

        }

 /**
     * *Check the shared preferences and set them accordingly
     */
    private void checkSharedPreferences()
{
    String cardviewsnal = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.cardviewsnal),"false");
    String colorCardview = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.colorCardview),"#ffffff");
    String textcolorsnal = mPreferences.getString (getString (R.string.textcolorsnal),"#2b434f");

    if(cardviewsnal.equals ("false")){
        cardView.setEnabled (true);
    }
    else
    {
        cardView.setEnabled (false);
    }

    if(colorCardview.equals ("#ffffff"))
    {
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
    }
    else
    {
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
    }

    if(textcolorsnal.equals ("#2b434f"))
    {
        textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
    }
    else {
        textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
    }
}
```

Comment: if your app need to persistent till it destroy than use static boolean variables for mange click .or
if your app need to persistent till it uninstall than use shared preference(boolean variable for manage). and manage it's value , maybe there are other solution out there , without researching I can provide this solution.